# Anomaly: Found a self-signed ssl certificate on my server

Tags: security, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a web app which runs on a load-balancer system (with nginx) that balances loads between three  instances (everything on top of OVH public cloud). 
Every of the three instances has a comodo ssl certificate installed on it. Since this morning, some users found out that sometimes while trying to connect to the website via chrome, the browser returned the "not private connection" message with error ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.
After some research, I found that one of those three instances presented another SSL self-signed certificate that no-one of my team obviously installed. Those are the infos:

[image: SSL CERTIFICATE INFO:]

If I go to swicha.info, I just see a strange site with a "Watch this" title and a continuous page-refreshing.

Could you help me in understanding how is it possible that someone installed another server certificate on my domain?? Do you think it's a man in the middle attack or something like that? For now, I just disconnected the server instance from the load balancer and I don't have certificate issues anymore but...what do you think the problem could be? Thank you !

Comment: Check what certificate you have installed. Then call each server directly, from the local network e.g. via curl. Also check if load balancer points to some extra server that you may have forgotten.

Comment: I tried all the operations you've listed but nothing...it seems that there's nothing wrong with the load balancing configuration :\

Comment: You say &quot;since this morning&quot;. Check the validity of your certificates. May be one of them on one of the nodes has expired today.

Comment: The certificate expires on July,19... :(

Comment: You say "some users". Can it be that these users have installed some malicious extention in Chrome? Check that. Take a separate computer. Remove there Chrome and install it from scratch. Access your web site / application many times (to make sure that each of your servers was called). If you cannot reproduce it, the problem can be related to these particular users: their Chrome with extensions or a virus or some malicious code on their operating system. And access your web site / application from another network, e.g. from your home WLAN or from your smart phone.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now. Take a look at your server security :p.